# How to fix AWS Config generating AccessDenied error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to allow AWS Config to write to a non-public S3 bucket.

Based on [the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/iamrole-permissions.html), I should have two policies assigned to the AWS role. However, It is not possible to add any policy to the service-linked role, neither to create a custom new service-linked role for AWS config.

[image: AWS Policy]
As such, how can I stop receiving the S3 AccessDenied error without making the bucket public?

edit: here is the error log:

```
{
"eventVersion": "1.07",
"userIdentity": {
    "type": "AssumedRole",
    "principalId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:AWSConfig-BucketConfigCheck",
    "arn": "arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/AWSServiceRoleForConfig/AWSConfig-BucketConfigCheck",
    "accountId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "accessKeyId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "sessionContext": {
        "sessionIssuer": {
            "type": "Role",
            "principalId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "arn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/aws-service-role/config.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForConfig",
            "accountId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "userName": "AWSServiceRoleForConfig"
        },
        "attributes": {
            "creationDate": "2020-04-30T00:43:57Z",
            "mfaAuthenticated": "false"
        }
    },
    "invokedBy": "AWS Internal"
},
"eventTime": "2020-04-30T00:43:57Z",
"eventSource": "s3.amazonaws.com",
"eventName": "PutObject",
"awsRegion": "eu-west-1",
"sourceIPAddress": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
"userAgent": "[AWSConfig]",
"errorCode": "AccessDenied",
"errorMessage": "Access Denied",
"requestParameters": {
    "bucketName": "aws-config-bucket-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Host": "aws-config-bucket-xxxxxxxxxxxx.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
    "x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control",
    "x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256",
    "key": "AWSLogs/xxxxxxxxxxxx/Config/ConfigWritabilityCheckFile"
},
"responseElements": null,
"additionalEventData": {
    "SignatureVersion": "SigV4",
    "CipherSuite": "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA",
    "bytesTransferredIn": 0,
    "AuthenticationMethod": "AuthHeader",
    "x-amz-id-2": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=",
    "bytesTransferredOut": 243
},
"requestID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"eventID": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"readOnly": false,
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "AWS::S3::Object",
        "ARN": "arn:aws:s3:::aws-config-bucket-xxxxxxxxxxxx/AWSLogs/xxxxxxxxxxxx/Config/ConfigWritabilityCheckFile"
    },
    {
        "accountId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
        "ARN": "arn:aws:s3:::aws-config-bucket-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
],
"eventType": "AwsApiCall",
"managementEvent": false,
"recipientAccountId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"vpcEndpointId": "vpce-xxxxxxxx",
"eventCategory": "Data"
```

}

Comment: When you use the AWS Config console to create an IAM role, AWS Config automatically attaches the required permissions to the role for you. Why do you want to change the policies attached to the auto-generated IAM role?

Comment: See: [Permissions for the Amazon S3 Bucket - AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-policy.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein , even with the modified S3 bucket policy, I still get the same error.

Comment: @jarmod I wanted to modify the role, because the role generates AccessDenied errors. Sorry if it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately no, if you have a solution, I'll be very happy to know it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-policy.html#required-permissions-in-another-account

> When AWS Config sends configuration information to an Amazon S3
> bucket in another account, **it first attempts to use the IAM role**, but
> this attempt fails if the access policy for the bucket does not grant
> WRITE access to the IAM role. In this event, AWS Config sends the
> information again, this time as the AWS Config service principal.

I checked my logs and there was an AWS Config service principal log, the same second as the AccessDenied, that was being accepted. Therefore, the error can be safely ignored. I have updated my Cloudwatch alarm to ignore it:

```
{($.errorCode="*UnauthorizedOperation") || (($.errorCode="AccessDenied*") && (($.userIdentity.type!="AssumedRole") || ($.userAgent!="[AWSConfig]")))}
```